# Start a new line before align in equation

Tags: equations, align

I use

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p(z_{di, dj} = t | w^{(k)}_{di} = w_i, z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{dj} = w_j, z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)
&\propto p(z_{di, dj} = t, w^{(k)}_{di} = w_i, w^{(n)}_{dj} = w_j | z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)\\
&= \frac{p(z, w^{(k)}, w^{(n)}| A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)}{p(z_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}| A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

to generate the following equation
[image]

But the equation is too long, so some of the result can not be seen in the pdf file. I want to start a new line before aligning. How can I do it so the result would be like follows:

> p(z, w........very long)
>
> = p(...)
>
> = p(...)

Comment: To start a new line, just add \\ at the end of the first one. The last \\ is superfluous btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first line is very long. Maybe you can do more splits in order to get it easier to read and type-set. But here is what you have asked for.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \MoveEqLeft[0]p(z_{di, dj} = t | w^{(k)}_{di} = w_i, z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{dj} = w_j, z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)\nonumber\\
    &\propto p(z_{di, dj} = t, w^{(k)}_{di} = w_i, w^{(n)}_{dj} = w_j | z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)\nonumber\\
    &= \frac{p(z, w^{(k)}, w^{(n)}| A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)}{p(z_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}| A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you can shorten your first line, you may increase the number in `\MoveEqLeft[]`. If you do not want a number on the right, just use `align*` instead (and get rid of the `\nonumber`s which are not needed any more).

Comment: Oops, you're right! Whereas loading the `geometry` package alters the value of `\textwidth` (from 345pt to 430pt), loading `showframe` does not. Somehow, I had conflated `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` with `\usepackage{showframe}`. I'll delete my earlier comment, as well as this one in a little while.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p(z_{di, dj} = t | w^{(k)}_{di} & = w_i, z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{dj}                                                                                                  \\
                                & = w_j, z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)                                                                                  \\
                                & \propto p(z_{di, dj} = t, w^{(k)}_{di} = w_i, w^{(n)}_{dj}                                                                                            \\
                                & = w_j | z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)                                                \\
                                & = \frac{p(z, w^{(k)}, w^{(n)}| A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)}{p(z_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}| A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or even this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p(z_{di, dj} & = t | w^{(k)}_{di}                                                                                                                                    \\
             & = w_i, z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{dj}                                                                                                  \\
             & = w_j, z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)                                                                                  \\
             & \propto p(z_{di, dj}                                                                                                                                  \\
             & = t, w^{(k)}_{di}                                                                                                                                     \\
             & = w_i, w^{(n)}_{dj}                                                                                                                                   \\
             & = w_j | z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)                                                \\
             & = \frac{p(z, w^{(k)}, w^{(n)}| A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)}{p(z_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{-dj}| A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta)} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

would be more legible IMO.

Comment: This method is quite clear. Better than @LaRiFari 's method.

Comment: Most of the `=` symbols are *not* suitable as alignment points. The structure of the statement is as follows: Pr( X=x | Y=y, Z, W, U=u, etc ). If break the lines at the `=` symbols, the meaning of the entire statement is almost surely destroyed. If anything, line breaks should happen at suitably chosen commas.

Comment: @Mico: I have no idea about the structure of the statement. I looked at it as a mere equation.

Comment: See the approach I took in my answer -- the line breaks are consciously set to occur after commas or `|` symbols.

Answer (score 3):

I take it the expressions before and after the `\propto` symbol are of the form

```
Pr (X=x | Y=y, Z, W, U, V=v, ...)
```

and

```
Pr (X=x, Y=y, V=v | Z, W, U,  ...)
```

respectively. As such, it's not a good idea to choose the `=` symbols to introduce line breaks. Instead, line breaks should happen after either one of the commas or after the conditioning symbol, `|`.

To emphasize the structure of the equation, I suggest you (i) enlarge the parentheses a bit, (ii) replace `|` with `\bigm|` (to get better spacing as well as a larger symbol) and (iii) introduce line breaks only at commas and or `\bigm|` instances.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "aligned" environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&p\bigl(\,z_{di, dj} = t \bigm|  w^{(k)}_{di} = w_i, 
  z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{dj} = w_j, \\
&\mkern110mu  z_{-dj}, w^{(n)}_{-dj},  A, \alpha^{(k)} \alpha^{(n)}, \beta\, \bigr)\\
&\quad\propto p\bigl(\,z_{di, dj} = t, w^{(k)}_{di} = w_i, w^{(n)}_{dj} = w_j \bigm|  \\
&\mkern110mu  z_{-di}, x_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, z_{-dj},  w^{(n)}_{-dj}, A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)},  \beta\,\bigr)\\
&\quad= \frac{p\bigl(\,z, w^{(k)}, w^{(n)}\bigm|  A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta\,\bigr)}{
    p\bigl(\,z_{-di}, w^{(k)}_{-di}, w^{(n)}_{-dj} \bigm|  A, \alpha^{(k)}, \alpha^{(n)}, \beta\,\bigr)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```